# Why I get Error 500 when adding a variable in function?

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-500

I'm just learning python and flask, please help to get why the error appears here:

This code works:

```
def index():
     return "Hello {}! ".format('World')
```

But when I try to add any variable in def, it returns Error 500:

```
def index():
     a = 'World'
     return "Hello {}! ".format(a)
```

Full code:

```
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
     a = 'World'
     return "Hello {}! ".format(a)
```

> 

UPD:

Seems it was something with my .py file.
I deleted it and made it again with the same code, and now it works (still can't understand what was wrong).

This is what was in the stderr.log file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mylogin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/passenger_wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'test.py')
  File "/home/mylogin/virtualenv/domains/mysite.com/public_html/3.8/lib64/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "test.py", line 14
    return "Hello {}! ".format(a)
                                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
2021-03-22 00:13:52.908411 [UID:3129][1366181] Child process with pid: 1366856 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
```

Comment: That function works for me. Could you try running it without the sys.path.insert line and seeing if it works?

Comment: Look in the webserver error log for the actual error message.

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` below all imports does not make any difference.

Comment: It's important to learn the fundamentals of Python - in particular, how to test and debug code in isolation, and what the requirements are for indentation etc. - *before* trying to work with large third-party libraries like Flask.